# Bluebird - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, bluebird

Can you help me figure this out because I don't know what I'm missing here even though I am returning the value from my first promise? I am using AWS SDK for Node.js. This SDK has support for [Bluebird](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/).

Here's my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));

AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

const describeRegions = function dr() {
  const describeRegionsPromise = ec2.describeRegions().promise();
  const regions = [];

  describeRegionsPromise.then((data) => {
    data.Regions.forEach((region) => {
      regions.push(region.RegionName);
    });
    return regions; // should return the values to describeSnapshots
    // console.log(regions); // this works! prints the list of AWS regions e.g. us-east-1, ap-southeast-1
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};

const describeSnapshots = function ds1(regions) {
  console.log('Hello I am describeSnapshots!');
  console.log(regions); // should print regions from describeRegions
};

const start = function s() {
  describeRegions()
    .then(regions => describeSnapshots(regions));
};

start();
```

Here's the error:

```
$ node test.js
/Users/sysadmin/Desktop/test/test.js:29
    .then(regions => describeSnapshots(regions));
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at s (/Users/sysadmin/Desktop/test/test.js:29:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sysadmin/Desktop/test/test.js:32:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to return `describeRegionsPromise.then()` otherwise `regions`won't be returned:

```
const describeRegions = function dr() {
  const describeRegionsPromise = ec2.describeRegions().promise();
  const regions = [];

  return describeRegionsPromise.then((data) => {
    data.Regions.forEach((region) => {
      regions.push(region.RegionName);
    });
    return regions; // should return the values to describeSnapshots
    // console.log(regions); // this works! prints the list of AWS regions e.g. us-east-1, ap-southeast-1
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning anything from `describeSnapshots()`.

Add return to this:

```
return describeRegionsPromise.then((data) => {
```

Comment: Thanks too! I can't believe I missed that one.